# Determing if an integer/string is a palindrome, and returning the reversed string/integer if it isn't

Tags: java, boolean, reverse, palindrome

I'm trying to to determine if a string or integer is a palindrome (same, if reversed). I've written a few methods, however, when I run the code, I keep getting an error for my isPalindromeString() and isPalindromeInteger() methods, saying the methods "must return a boolean type." I have setup clauses in the methods to return true/false based on my if statements. Not sure what I'm doing wrong here. Any guidance would be appreciated. Thanks. PS: I'm trying to not use any arrays, data structures and/or class methods.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    

    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    String userInput;
    System.out.println("Would you like to enter a string or integer?");
    userInput = keyboard.nextLine().toLowerCase();
    
    while(!userInput.equals("string") && !userInput.equals("integer"))
    {
        System.out.println("Invalid input. Try again. ");
        userInput = keyboard.nextLine().toLowerCase();
    }
    
    if(userInput.equals("string"))
    {
        System.out.println("Enter the string now: ");
        String s;
        s = keyboard.nextLine();
        
        if(isPalindromeString(s))
        {
            System.out.println("Yes, the string is a palindrome.");
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("No, the string is not a palindrome.");
            System.out.println("The reverse of the string is: " + reverseString(s));
        }
    }
    else if(userInput.equals("integer"))
    {
        System.out.println("Enter the number now: ");
        int i;
        i = keyboard.nextInt();
        
        if(isPalindromeInteger(i))
        {
            System.out.println("Yes, the integer is a palindrome.");
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("No, the integer is not a palindrome.");
            System.out.println("The reverse of the integer is: " + reverseInteger(i));
        }
        
        keyboard.nextLine();
        
    }

        
        
}

public static boolean isPalindromeInteger(int a)
{

    int counter=0;

    String s = Integer.toString(a);
    int reverseCounter = s.length()-1;
    if(isEven(s.length()))
    {
        
        while(counter!=(s.length()/2))
        {
            if(s.charAt(counter)!=s.charAt(reverseCounter))
            {
                return false;
            }
            
                
            counter++;
            reverseCounter--;
        }
        return true;
        
    }
    else if(!isEven(s.length()))
    {
        while(counter!= (s.length()/2))
        {
            if(s.charAt(counter)!=s.charAt(reverseCounter))
            {
                return  false;
            }
            
        
                
            counter++;
            reverseCounter--;
        }
        return  true;
        
    }
        
}


public static boolean isPalindromeString(String s)
{
    int counter=0;
    int reverseCounter = s.length()-1;
    
    if(isEven(s.length()))
    {
        
        while(counter!=(s.length()/2))
        {
            if(s.charAt(counter)!=s.charAt(reverseCounter))
            {
                return false;
            }
            
            counter++;
            reverseCounter--;
            
        }
        return true;
        
    }
    else if(!isEven(s.length()))
    {
        while(counter!= (s.length()/2))
        {
            if(s.charAt(counter)!=s.charAt(reverseCounter))
            {
                return false;
            }
            counter++;
            reverseCounter--;
        
        }
        
        return true;
    }
    

}

public static int reverseInteger(int a)
{
    String s = Integer.toString(a);
    
    String temp = new String();
    
    for(int i = (s.length()-1); i >=0; i--)
    {
        temp = temp + s.charAt(i);
    }
    
    int num = Integer.parseInt(temp);
    
    return num;
}

public static String reverseString(String s)
{
    String temp = new String();
    
    for(int i = (s.length()-1); i >=0; i--)
    {
        temp = temp + s.charAt(i);
    }
    
    return temp;
}

public static boolean isEven(int a)
{
    if(a % 2 ==0)
        return true;
    else 
        return false;
}
```

Comment: Remove the complementary condition. It's 'obvious" to you that `!isEven(...)` is true if `isEven(...)` was false; but the compile disagrees, because it doesn't know whether that method is pure in its inputs. Turn the `else if` into `else`.

Comment: Your code will get a compilation error. It cannot be `run`.

Answer (score 1):

In both your `isPalindromeString()` and `isPalindromeInteger()` methods, you do not have a return statement outside of your if/elif blocks. Simply adding a `return false` after your else if check should make your code work.

Comment: Why `return false`?

Comment: I just assumed that if the code does not enter any of the if statements, then there would be an issue with the parameter or the condition itself.